# Is a function continuous at every point necessarily a function that can be drawn 'smoothly'?

Tags: real-analysis

To say $f$ is continuous at $a$ is to say that no matter how much you 'zoom in', $f$ and $f(a)$ will always be 'touching'.

This is why we describe functions that can be drawn 'smoothly' as continuous$-$or more exactly as continuous at every point.

But is a function that is continuous at every point necessarily a function that can be drawn 'smoothly'?

Edit: I am examining this phenomenon soley through the $\delta-\epsilon$ lens. I'm still only a first-year student!

Comment: Depends on what you mean by smoothly.

Comment: you could draw it without interrupting your pencil flow

Comment: I don't think so. There exists functions that are continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere. For such kind of functions, it would be nearly impossible to draw them in the plane, let alone "smoothly".

Comment: Mathematics is *precise*.  If you want to ask a question about mathematics, you need to be very clear about the terms that you are using and what they mean.  In your question, you have given a very vague "definition" of continuity, and have not explained what you mean by "drawing smoothly".  Without understanding these terms, I don't think that a useful answer can be provided.  I have voted to close the question as "Unclear."

Comment: The graph of a continuous function is always path-connected, but I doubt one can draw fractals with a pencil.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am trying to understand the oft-given 'intuitive' interpretation  for the delta-epsilon definition of continuity.

Comment: In analysis, lots of times, intuition may be incorrect, and probably lead you into mistake.

Comment: @user_hello1 Again, be precise.  What does it mean for $f$ to be "touching" $f(a)$?  What does it mean to "draw [a function] smoothly"?  What is the precise statement of the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity which you have in mind?  My understanding is that you are looking for something like a proof of the intermediate value theorem, but the word "smooth" has special meaning in mathematics, and I can't tell if you are using it in that special way, or in a more vernacular way.  Once again:  be precise.

Comment: @user_hello1. The intuitive idea of *smoothness* might be misleading. Consider a function $f: \mathbb Q \rightarrow \mathbb Q$ defined as $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-2}.$$ This function is continuous in $\mathbb Q$... No way to draw it *without interrupting the pencil flow.*

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague and so perhaps that this is not an answer, but I would say that a continuous nowhere differentiable function is impossible to draw. Consider the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function). Take a look at the diagrams at this page. I suppose that it is clear why the text has no graphic of the Weierstrass function: it cannot be drawn!